# Execution works with personal access token, but not using AAD access token for Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, access-token, azure-devops-rest-api

I have my below code which output the master branch stats in JSON format from Azure DevOps repository and I am capturing the required output. This works when I use the personal access token the authentication works and gets back with the results from the API.

But when I try to generate Access token using the registered app in AAD(has delegated user impersonation enabled for Azure DevOps under API permissions), I am able to generate the access token and then passing it while calling the API, but it returns back with

> StatusCode: 203, ReasonPhrase: 'Non-Authoritative Information', Version: 1.1, Content: `System.Net.Http.StreamContent`

```
public static async Task GetBuilds()
{
    string url = "Azure Dev-Ops API";
    var personalaccesstoken = "personalaccesscode";
    //var personalaccesstoken = token.GetYourTokenWithClientCredentialsFlow().Result;
    string value = null;

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", personalaccesstoken))));
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody);
        value = jsonObject;
    }
}

if (value != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
}

public static async Task<string> GetYourTokenWithClientCredentialsFlow()
{
    string tokenUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant ID}/oauth2/token";
    var tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl);

    tokenRequest.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["grant_type"] = "client_credentials",
        ["client_id"] = "client ID",
        ["client_secret"] = "client secret",
        ["resource"] = "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
    });

    dynamic json;
    dynamic token;
    string accessToken;

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var tokenResponse = client.SendAsync(tokenRequest).Result;
    json = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    accessToken = token.access_token;
    return accessToken;
}
```

Tried to test using postman using the access token generated using above code and get as below screenshot.

[image]

what I am doing wrong here and how can I fix the problem?

Comment: If you want to access Azure Devops API, your resource should be “499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798”. For more details, please refer to https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/ManagedClientConsoleAppSample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The azure ad access token is a bearer token. You do not need to use it as basic auth.

Try with the following code:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", GetYourTokenWithClientCredentialsFlow().Result);
```

**Update:**

1. Register a new app
   [image]
2. Set the app as a public client by default
   [image]
3. Add permission to DevOps API
   [image]
4. Create a new project, install **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory** package
   [image]
5. Code sample

```
class Program
{
    static string azureDevOpsOrganizationUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/jack0503/"; //change to the URL of your Azure DevOps account; NOTE: This must use HTTPS
    static string clientId = "0a1f****-****-****-****-a2a4****7f69";          //change to your app registration's Application ID
    static string replyUri = "https://localhost/";                     //change to your app registration's reply URI
    static string azureDevOpsResourceId = "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798"; //Constant value to target Azure DevOps. Do not change  
    static string tenant = "hanxia.onmicrosoft.com";     //your tenant ID or Name
    static String GetTokenInteractively()
    {
        AuthenticationContext ctx = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant); ;
        IPlatformParameters promptBehavior = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto | PromptBehavior.SelectAccount);
        AuthenticationResult result = ctx.AcquireTokenAsync(azureDevOpsResourceId, clientId, new Uri(replyUri), promptBehavior).Result;
        return result.AccessToken;
    }

    static String GetToken()
    {
        AuthenticationContext ctx = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant); ;
        UserPasswordCredential upc = new UserPasswordCredential("jack@hanxia.onmicrosoft.com", "yourpassword");
        AuthenticationResult result = ctx.AcquireTokenAsync(azureDevOpsResourceId, clientId, upc).Result;
        return result.AccessToken;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //string token = GetTokenInteractively();
        string token = GetToken();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(azureDevOpsOrganizationUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("_apis/projects").Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tSuccesful REST call");
                var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            else if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get the same response :-(

Comment: You cannot use client credential flow. You need to sign as an user. Check my update later.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information. I will try on this, but not sure about the delegation part on how car I can grant consent as its disabled by default. Currently added the Azure devOps API permission for the app. Will keep you posted.

Comment: The button is used for admin to grant consent for the whole tenant. As the DevOps API permission can be consented by the user himself, you can use interactive login for one time. This will grant the consent for the user only.

Comment: Perfect! I had to get my organization approval for the admin consent and that fixed my problem. You have been the best help with proper instructions that anyone could understand easily. Thanks a lot for taking your time and helping on this.